# "I am happy because I am rich." Exactly which part does the subordinate clause modify?

Tags: modifiers

"I am happy **because I am rich**."

Is it the adjective "happy" or the verb "am" or the entire predicate "am happy" that the subordinate clause "because I am rich" modifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am happy* [*because I am rich*].

The subordinate clause is "I am rich".

The bracketed element is a preposition phrase headed by the preposition "because", with the subordinate clause as its complement.

The preposition phrase is functioning as an adjunct of reason in clause structure, i.e. it's a modifier in (and thus part of) the VP "am happy because I am rich".

Comment: Exactly which part does the subordinate clause modify? *Because* is not a conjunction?

Comment: @YosefBaskin As I said, the subordinate clause is a **complement** of the prep "because", so it doesn't modify anything. Modern grammar classifies "because" as a preposition. There's plenty of info about this on the 'Net, e.g. [link](https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/01/because-why-the-word-is-not-a-conjunction-as-dictionaries-have-it-but-instead-a-preposition.html)

Comment: So the adjunct "because I am rich" _modifies_ the verb "am" while "happy" is a predicative complement, where all of them are constituents of the verb phrase "am happy because I am rich" headed by the verb "am"?

Comment: @Expressivist Not quite: the adjunct "because I am rich" modifies the verb phrase "am happy". The VP consists of  three constituents: (1) the predicator (verb) "am", (2) subject complement "happy" and (3) the adjunct "because I am rich".